# Siemens PLC S7-1200 - Connection to internet via server

Tags: networking, plc, s7-1200, siemens

I have made the s7-1200 webserver and want to access it from a remote location in addition to configuring the PLC program if needed. The PLC has access to internet through a router at the location. I do not want to use VPN or port forwarding.

I want to rent a server and access the PLC through this server. 
Typically:  https://host1.no/client/cart.php?language=English&gid=15 .

Question:
What siemens-equipment is needed for me to connect to that server through internet such that I can connect to that server with any PC and access the PLC webserver and also compile new programs to the PLC.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you connect a PLC directly to the Internet, give it a password!

With Extended Download you can type in the IP Address of the PLC. Be aware that your ISP should allow port 102 (S7 protocol) and this port must be forwarded by the router to the PLC if the PLC is connected via a router to the internet.